# external library error while running AWS Glue job

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I have placed the external python libraries (*.whl) in S3 and is accessing the same by mentioning the path in AWS Glue Job 'Python library path' argument.

It runs fine for few external modules but fails for others with the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/processing", line 2, in <module> import netCDF4 File "/tmp/netCDF4-1.5.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl/netCDF4/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ._netCDF4 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netCDF4._netCDF4'
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: using wheels on `sys.path` doesn't work for binary dependencies (`*.so`)

Comment: What shall I do to solve it or any workaround?